# Python urllib with proxy not working while C# works

Tags: c#, python, proxy, urllib

I am trying to get data from an API using python 'urllib.request'. My requests sometime need to post json data.

My network is behind a proxy

When i try to get the data using C# code, everything works great:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
WebProxy wp = new WebProxy("{IP}", 8080);
wc.Proxy = wp;
var request = "https://{API address and params}";
Uri serviceUri = new Uri(request);
string download = wc.DownloadString(serviceUri);
```

My python code is:

```
import urllib

address = "https://{API address and params}"
req = urllib.request.Request(address)
req.set_proxy("{IP}:8080", "http")
response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
```

My python code throws a 400 error code exception - 'bad request'

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: what is API and params? or its confidential :) ?

Comment: @VivekSable does it really matters? its a commercial API with a key i cannot share here

Comment: Can you check implementation of API? Write log in API implementation, The `400` means your respective API view is not get correct parameters or token i.e. validation on parameters fails.

Comment: But the exact same request works in c# as i mentioned.. the params are correct

Comment: can u see how you set proxy actually? I want to see `http` or `https` entry in settings

Comment: i don't understand what do you want to see.. sorry
i use req.set_proxy("10.0.xx.xx:8080", "http")

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142695/discussion-between-gil-kr-and-vivek-sable).